# Trying to get the average value of the elements, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

My assignment is to Implement the `getSpeedStatistic` function, that accepts the `testResults` array and returns statistics as an array with 3 numbers:

The first one is the lowest value.
The second is the highest value.
The last one is the average value, rounded down.

My function:

```
function getSpeedStatistic(testResults) {
  let min = testResults[0];
  let max = testResults[0];
  let sum = 0;
  let average = 0;

  for(const number of testResults){

    if(number > max){
      max = number;
    };

    if(number  < min){
      min = number;
    };

    sum += number;
    average += Math.round(sum / testResults.length);
  };
  return [min, max, average];
};
```

It works for the lowest and highest value but it doesn't return the right average, I cant seem to find a pattern for the results either, it seems like it gives me random numbers, I don't understand the issue.

For example:

It should return `[0, 8, 3]` when input is `[5, 0, 8, 1]` - but it returns `[0,8,9]`;

Should return `[1, 18, 4]` when input is `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 18]` - but it returns `[1,18,11]`.

Should return `[1, 9.2, 5]` when input is `[4.5, 6.7, 9.2, 1]` - but it returns `[1,9.2,14]`

Please help!

Comment: You can wait until after the loop to compute the average; there's no reason to compute it within every iteration.

Comment: Should your average really be calculated during the for loop, or just once? :)

Comment: Once............

Comment: @TSR well that was a question to make the OP think :D

Comment: is Math methods, min and max, and reduce can be used to sum the array values to get an average https://playcode.io/1035477 is a waste of lines looping just to loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```js
function getSpeedStatistic(testResults) {
 let lowest = testResults[0]
 let highest = testResults[0]
 let sum = 0
testResults.forEach (num => {
    if (num < lowest){
       lowest = num
    }
    else if (num > highest){
       highest = num
    } 
    sum += num
 })

 return [lowest, highest, Math.floor(sum/testResults.length)]
};

console.log(getSpeedStatistic([5, 0, 8, 1])) // Example
```

In the `forEach` loop each time we check if the value is less than `lowest` variable if yes we equal that to the new number and this process is the same for defining the highest number but we check if number is higher than `highest` variable.

Each time we sum the number in the loop in `sum` variable and when we want to output the result we simply divide that by the length of the array (average) and then floor it to round it down.

Answer (score 0):

Put the average outside and after the for loop

```
function getSpeedStatistic(testResults) {
  let min = testResults[0];
  let max = testResults[0];
  let sum = 0;
  let average = 0;

  for(const number of testResults){

    if(number > max){
      max = number;
    };

    if(number  < min){
      min = number;
    };

    sum += number;

  };
    average += Math.round(sum / testResults.length);
  return [min, max, average];
};
```

Comment: Also, not sure why you are rounding your average but I kept it the way it is